# OpenGL trying to stretch quad with texture but stretches triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote code to reshape a quad that has been textured. When I stretch the quad the image does stretch how I would expect. I seems like when I stretch the image there are two different triangles that the image is stretch over vs. one single quad. Pixels in the upper left stretch together but they don't effect the pixels in the lower right. And vice verse. Is there a setting I should set to stretch across the entire quad.

Here is an image:

[image]

To work my code you can used the arrow keys to move the corners. Press the space bar to switch which corner is being controlled.

my code

```
// textureMapping.cpp
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


static GLuint texName;
int mode = 0;
double tol = 0.2f;

double xLoc = 0.0;
double yLoc = 0.0;

double xLocLL = 0.0;
double yLocLL = 0.0;

double xLocUL = 0.0;
double yLocUL = 0.0;

double xLocLR = 0.0;
double yLocLR = 0.0;

double xLocUR = 0.0;
double yLocUR = 0.0;

void init(void)
{    

   cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.tiff");
  //cv::Mat flipped;
  //cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);
  //image = flipped;
  if(image.empty()){
      std::cout << "image empty" << std::endl;
  }else{
      cv::flip(image, image, 0);
      glGenTextures(1, &texName);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Set texture clamping method
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);


      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
                     0,                 // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
                     GL_RGB,            // Internal colour format to convert to
                     image.cols,          // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
                     image.rows,          // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
                     0,                 // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
                     GL_BGR, // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
                     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // Image data type
                     image.ptr());        // The actual image data itself

      glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  }
}

void display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1.0+xLoc+xLocLL, -1.0+yLoc+yLocLL, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1.0+xLoc+xLocUL, 1.0+yLoc+yLocUL, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(1.0+xLoc+xLocUR, 1.0+yLoc+yLocUR, 0.0);
   glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(1.0+xLoc+xLocLR, -1.0+yLoc+yLocLR, 0.0);
   //glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1.0+xLoc, -1.0+yLoc, 0.0);
   //glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1.0+xLoc, 1.0+yLoc, 0.0);
   //glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(1.0+xLoc, 1.0+yLoc, 0.0);
   //glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(1.0+xLoc, -1.0+yLoc, 0.0);
   glEnd();
   glFlush();
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1.0, 30.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.6);
}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      case 32:
         mode += 1;
         if (mode == 5)
         {
            mode = 0;
         }
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {

   switch(key) {
      case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
         switch(mode)
         {
            case 0:
               xLoc -= tol;
               break;
            case 1:
               xLocLL -= tol;
               break;
            case 2:
               xLocUL -= tol;
               break;
            case 3:
               xLocUR -= tol;
               break;
            case 4:
               xLocLR -= tol;
               break;
         }
         break;
      case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
         switch(mode)
         {
            case 0:
               xLoc += tol;
               break;
            case 1:
               xLocLL += tol;
               break;
            case 2:
               xLocUL += tol;
               break;
            case 3:
               xLocUR += tol;
               break;
            case 4:
               xLocLR += tol;
               break;
         }
         break;
      case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
         switch(mode)
         {
            case 0:
               yLoc -= tol;
               break;
            case 1:
               yLocLL -= tol;
               break;
            case 2:
               yLocUL -= tol;
               break;
            case 3:
               yLocUR -= tol;
               break;
            case 4:
               yLocLR -= tol;
               break;
         }
         break;
      case GLUT_KEY_UP:
         switch(mode)
         {
            case 0:
               yLoc += tol;
               break;
            case 1:
               yLocLL += tol;
               break;
            case 2:
               yLocUL += tol;
               break;
            case 3:
               yLocUR += tol;
               break;
            case 4:
               yLocLR += tol;
               break;
         }
         break;
   }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
   init();
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutIdleFunc(display);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
   glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);

   glutMainLoop();
   return 0; 
}
```

Makefile

```
textureMapping: textureMapping.cpp
    g++ -o textureMapping textureMapping.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

Comment: You can't do that mapping that way. You need to use a projective texture space to define projective texture mappings. [This page](http://www.xyzw.us/~cass/qcoord/) explains the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's correct behaviour. The GL specification (prior to 3.0) permits quads to be drawn as pairs of triangles, which is what you're seeing. Quads were removed from the spec entirely in 3.0.

If you're expecting it to look like a quad with perspective then you need actually to supply 3d coordinates.

If you're expecting OpenGL to guess what perspective transform would have been applied to get a rectangle to bend to the 2d shape you're pushing then you're out of look. That's a highly application-specific feature. You should look up homography.